# Отличие запуска Topshelf и Console Application

Tags: c#, excel

Есть программа-служба, написанная с помощью `Topshelf`. В ней происходит открытие файлов Excel с помощью `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. При запуске программы как консольного приложения всё работает хорошо, но при установке службы и запуске как службы происходит ошибка при попытке открытия файла excel. Запуск службы происходит от имени профиля, под которым и выполнялся запуск консольного приложения.

```
Application application = new Application();
Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path); //здесь срабатывает Exception
```

Получаю такую ошибку: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Нет доступа к файлу 'd:\\Programs\\AccountingEmailHandler\\post\\Приложение к ППИ.xls'. Это может быть вызвано одной из следующих причин. Имени файла или пути не существует. Файл используется другой программой. Имя книги, которую вы пытаетесь сохранить, совпадает с именем открытой в данный момент книги.`

Может есть какая-то разница в двух способах запуска?

```
HostFactory.Run(factory =>
{
    factory.UseAutofacContainer(container);
    factory.Service<EmailService>(service =>
    {
        service.ConstructUsingAutofacContainer();
        service.WhenStarted(eksana => eksana.Start());
        service.WhenStopped(eksana => eksana.Stop());
    });
    factory.RunAsLocalSystem();
    factory.SetServiceName("AccountingEmailHandler");
    factory.SetDisplayName("Accounting Email Handler");
    factory.SetDescription("Служба для разбора писем электронной почты бухгалтерии от банков, почты и прочего.");
});
```

Код запуска. Имя пользователя для запуска выбирал из списка уже после установки службы в её настройках.

Comment: пользователя, от имени которого работает служба, корректно задайте

Comment: а код запуска через TopShelf покажете?

Comment: ну вот наверное вам не нужен RunAsLocalSystem();